# doctrine GeneratedValue=NONE keeps inserting NULL for Id

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

this is my entity:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="custom_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $customId;

    public function __construct( $customId )
    {
        $this->customId = $customId;
    }

}
```

now i'm generating a new instance

```
$foo = new Foo(123);
dump($foo); // shows customId: 123
$em->persist($foo);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO table_foo
>   (custom_id, foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null,
>   null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'custom_id' cannot be null

I know that it can't be NULL, thats why I'm setting it.
Why does doctrine overrides the value with NULL? strategy is *NONE* and taking place in the constructor... What am I missing here?

Comment: NONE means: Make it null. Remove the @ORM\Generated... line completely.

Comment: "NONE: Tells Doctrine that the identifiers are assigned (and thus generated) by your code. The assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to EntityManager#persist. NONE is the same as leaving off the @GeneratedValue entirely." i did remove it and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but in case that someone will search for it you need to use custom value generator (does nothing just put your into insert statement)

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="custom_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator")
 */
private $customId;
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
```

Comment: "NONE: Tells Doctrine that the identifiers are assigned (and thus generated) by your code. The assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to EntityManager#persist. NONE is the same as leaving off the @GeneratedValue entirely." i did and the result is the same